# Android Studio doesn't recognize VT-X while running on Linux VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kali-linux, android-studio, vt-x

So recently i've been trying to install android studio on my Kali linux virtual machine to run some emulators for pentesting. Only problem is that i cant run a emulator in android studio because my processor supposedly doesn't support virtualization.
Inside the bios of the host VT-X is enabled and Hyper-V is disabled.
Anyone a clue how to fix this?

Comment: What VM / hypervisor with Hyper-V disabled? VirtualBox? VMWare? Most likely you'll need to get nested virtualization enabled, assuming the hypervisor you use supports that.

Comment: ... the VM itself needs VT-X to function, so it is "in use". Now: is there a way to provide "simulated" VT-X inside the VM? VMWare, Virtualbox, ...